# AngularJS JasmineJS decorated $log object not injected correctly

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to AngularJS and JasmineJS.

I have decorated the Angular $log service to do logging over http.  I verified that it works fine in the program itself.  However, when running the Jasmine unit tests, the $log calls create errors.  I get messages such as the following:

> TypeError: TypeError: $log.warn.logs is undefined in
>   http...[snip]...angular-mocks.js (line 316)

The messages follow this pattern for all the different $log functions ($log.error.logs, $log.info.logs, etc.).

My current injector looks like this:

```
var $httpBackend, log;

beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, $log) {
    log = $log;

     //lots of mock http service things here
}));
```

I have also tried this:

```
beforeEach(inject(['$log', function (log) {
    $log = log;
}]));
```

And this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
     log = $injector.get('$log');

     // mock http things here
}));
```

A failing test looks like this:

```
it('should log error', function () {
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('the url for logging');
    var controller = createController();
    log.warn('Test warning');
    $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

All calls to $log in the code being tested result in the same error.  When I commented them out and removed the failing test above, all unit tests passed.

How should I set up the unit tests correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that there is something wrong with angular-mocks.js and it is not instantiating the log arrays correctly.  I downloaded the latest non-beta copy, and it's still doing the same thing.  The instantiation of arrays happens in their code using a call to $log.reset(), but somehow, that part of their code is not being reached.  Therefore, I fixed my problem by manually calling $log.reset():

```
 //This works
 var $log;
 beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
     $log = $injector.get('$log');
     $log.reset();

     //continue other stuff
 }));

 //This also works
 var log;
 beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, $log) {
    log = $log;
    log.reset();

    //continue other stuff
 }));
```